# PTIJ: How do I debug my program?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

While I found a [whole](https://www.star-k.org/images/pdf/bugchecking_july3.pdf) bunch of [guides](http://www.crcweb.org/fruit%20&%20veg%20guide.php) on how to remove bugs from my Cabbage, Lettuce, or strawberries, I never found any guide on how to remove bugs from my program?

Can someone help me here?

Oh, and if I can't [guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) my program is free of bugs, is it now as bad as a strawberry and forbidden?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18684594#18684594

Answer (score 5):

All kosher software should be developed hydroponically. Developers can sit in a pool or the dead sea while writing code.

You don't need to guarantee a program is free of bugs, just a statistical sample will suffice: If you examine three select samples of code carefully and find no bugs, you can assume the rest of the program is bug free.

Comment: Wow, what a simple procedure!  I can't wait to show it to those snooty test-driven development guys.

Answer (score 2):

Save the program on an external hard drive, cut said hard drive in half, soak in a transparent or light-colored bowl filled with water for 3 hours. Check for bugs and repeat until none are found. It is reccomended that you mix some rubbing alcohol and/or battery acid into the water.

Comment: I also recommend that once you save your files on the drive, you should compress those files by placing the hard drive in the freezer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check computer programs for bugs. All computer programs are under the supervision of the **BDT"Z** which stands for Bugs Destroyed Then Zapped.

In other words, this organization not only removes the bugs for you, but after the bugs have been removed, they zap them with gigabytes of useless computer data. This process assures that these bugs can never crawl back and infest any computer programs.

Comment: I.       AgReeeee wדכlässt DwnFF. Techmologee maקs  טgs. A thiñg of ßast

Comment: @JJLL It looks like your comment has bugs!